# How to store an init call in an NSInvocation?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uipageviewcontroller, nsinvocation

I'm trying to set up an app that works with UIPageViewController. I technically could instantiate all the view at once and put them in an array, but that would be expensive, and it seems better to initialize the views as needed. I read that an NSInvocation is a message rendered static-- so I was thinking I could have an array that basically contains: `[SubclassA alloc]init], [SubclassB alloc]init], etc...` with those messages wrapped in an NSInvocation. I could then return the result of that message in pageViewController:ViewControllerAfter/BeforeViewController:.

I'm still pretty new at this, so it is very possible I am fundamentally misunderstanding NSInvocation, but either way, an answer would still be helpful.

Comment: I think what you're misunderstanding is UIPageViewController. There's no need to pre-store any invocations. Just respond as delegate by figuring out what view controller is needed, and create it, configure it, and return it.

Comment: I know, but I thought maybe the best way was to store those calls in an array and return them by index.

Comment: the idea of the delegation pattern is that you create the view controllers as needed and UIPageViewController holds those needed and releases the ones that aren't needed any more. Pre-creating / configuring VCs is OK for a few (2-4) but keep in mind that once they are displayed, they retain the complete view hierarchy and fill up memory.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't want a switch-case statement or a few ifs inside your delegate method? If it works and isn't too large or can be split up easily (e.g. like `if (..) { return [self createA]; } else { return [self createB] }`) this would be unnecessary over-engineering

Comment: I know what you thought. Try to bear in mind that you are the questioner; that means you don't know the answer. I'm telling you the answer. Drop your preconceptions and just do this the normal way. Here's a full discussion with sample code: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_page_view_controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want some kind of lazy instantiation.

You can use this helper class

```
@interface LazyObject : NSObject

@property (copy) id (^block)(void));
@property (readonly) id object;

+ (instancetype)create:(id (^)(void))block;

@end

@implementation LazyObject {
    id _object;
}

+ (instancetype)create:(id (^)(void))block
{
    LazyObject *obj = [[self alloc] init];
    obj.block = block;
    return obj;
}

- (id)object
{
    if (!_object) _object = self.block();
    return _object;
}

@end
```

---

```
NSArray *array = @[[LazyObject create:^id{ return [[SomeClassA alloc] init];}],
                   [LazyObject create:^id{ return [[SomeClassB alloc] init];}]];

SomeClassA *a = [array[0] object];
SomeClassB *b = [array[1] object];
```

---

As others said, `NSInvocation` is not a good solution for your *original* problem. It is designed to invoke method dynamically. You don't need it for most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

`NSInvocation` is for manipulating calls where you don't know the method or number/types of arguments until runtime. Here, the method called is fixed at compile time. You don't need `NSInvocation`.

If you want to store an action to perform as an object that you can put into an array, you should use blocks.